# How to use wavesurfer.js with a node bundler?

Tags: node.js, wavesurfer.js

I am trying to use wavesurfer.js with node bundler, as indicated here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/wavesurfer.js?activeTab=readme
but I can not get it working, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './../node_modules/wavesurfer.js/dist/wavesurfer.js' does not provide an export named 'default' (at TwoPlayers.js:2:9)
```

(I tried to import a module that I build without any troubles..., It seems like wavesurfer.js is not prepared to be load with import??)

Mi source code is:

```
import { LitElement, html, css } from "lit-element";
import  WaveSurfer    from 'wavesurfer.js';

import { MyFunction2 } from './demo'

// import * as WaveSurfer  from 'wavesurfer.js';

class TwoPlayers extends LitElement {
    static styles = css`
    :host {
        display: block;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
        padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
        background-color: #475119;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    `;
```

In the examples folder always is used as a library loaded in the HTML, but there aren't any example using node bundler.

Has anyone managed to get it working with node using import?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Using  this way to import the package:

```
import 'wavesurfer.js';
```

It will work, and you can use WaveSurfer object

The documentation say to use:

```
import WaveSurfer from 'wavesurfer.js';
```

but it is not working

Comment: This is the correct answer when you're using rollup and @rollup/plugin-node-resolve and get the error: RollupError: "default" is not exported by "node_modules/wavesurfer.js/dist/wavesurfer.js", imported by "...". Weird behaviour but good fix, thanks